# The simplest way to say "Split Videos Into Segments"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests, phrase-usage, titles

I've finished developing app for iOS that's splits video into multiple continuous segments. Meaning that if i'll take a video of 35 seconds and choose to split it with 10 sec durations. I'll get 4 videos:

- from 0  10 seconds
- from 10 to 20 seconds
- from 20 to 30 seconds
- from 30 to 35 seconds

Now I'm working on the creatives of the app, and I'm trying to think what is the shortest and most understandable way to describe it:

1. Split Videos Into Segments
2. Split Videos Into Pieces
3. Split Videos Into Short Clips

**What do you think, is there more options? Any help will be highly appreciated, as English is not my native language.**

**Best Regards,
Roi**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a "clip" refers to a sub-section of a larger video, **"Split Video(s) into Clips"** seems appropriate here. The nature of the word matches with the act of clipping film, as was done before digital video editing when film was literally clipped with scissors or a machine.